# Unity 3D - Random Platform Generator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, generator

I'm currently working on a project in Unity. It generates random pillars as platforms for the player to jump on. I want it to only spawn a pillar if `Vector3.Distance(itsRandomPosition, eachOtherPillarsPosition)` is greater or equal to `minDisBetweenPillars`.

After a lot of trying, it still doesn't work and spawn inside of each other. Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateRandPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject platformPrefab;
    public Transform map;

    public float minDisBetweenPillars;
    public float spawnRange;
    public float spawnRangeY;
    public int totPillars;

    private void Start()
    {
        SpawnPillars();
    }

    private bool CanSpawn(float min, Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
    {
        bool res = Vector3.Distance(a, b) >= min;
        return res == true;
    }

    private void SpawnPillars()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < totPillars; i++)
        {
            Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnRange, spawnRange), -30, Random.Range(-spawnRange, spawnRange));
            GameObject[] pillars = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Pillar");

            bool canSpawn = false;
            foreach (GameObject pillar in pillars)
            {
                Vector3 pillarPos = pillar.transform.position;

                if (CanSpawn(minDisBetweenPillars, spawnPos, pillarPos) == true)
                {
                    canSpawn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (canSpawn == true)
            {
                spawnPos.y = -30 + Random.Range(-spawnRangeY, spawnRangeY);
                Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity, map);
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're currently checking if the new pillar will be outside the range of ANY one of the existing ones.
What you want is a check, if it is outside the range of ALL of the existing ones:

```
bool canSpawn = true;
foreach (GameObject pillar in pillars)
{
    Vector3 pillarPos = pillar.transform.position;

    if (!CanSpawn(minDisBetweenPillars, spawnPos, pillarPos))
    {
        canSpawn = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also you might want to think about only checking x-z-distance. The calculation is cheaper and i suppose your pillars are y alligned, meaning the y distance will only falsify your result.

Comment: Thank you so much @Thomas! You really solved a _huge_ problem for me!